# Modify control (call back) to UI Thread from static method

Tags: wpf, multithreading, controls

I just modified a tool of mine to kick off a new Thread instead of running a static method inside of a static class. Naturally, I get errors because this new thread cant access the other thread.

But how would I adjust the below code do the same to the MainWindow/UI Thread now that they seperated?

**Thread t = new Thread(() => ParityHelper.MakeRequest(pack));**

Inside the static class I command the UI controls like this right now:

**((MainWindow)System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow).ListOfTestsBox.Items.Add("COOL");**

Comment: I have found thousands of posts, but none of them deal with a static class trying to reference a Control in the MainWindow.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to interact with objects from UI thread you should use Dispatcher (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.invoke(v=vs.110).aspx). For example:

```
Thread t = new Thread(() => Dispatcher.Invoke(() => ParityHelper.MakeRequest(pack)));
```

Answer (score 0):

// MainWindow.xaml.cs

public static MainWindow MainUI;

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MainUI = this;  // <---- IMPORTANT
    }
```

// in the other class (running in a thread)

```
    public delegate void DelTest();

    public static void Test()
    {
        Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(
            DispatcherPriority.Normal,
            new DelTest(ParityChecker.MainWindow.MainUI.Tester)); 
}
```